# How do I determine GMT offset corrected for DST? (Embedded system, no O/S but HTTP.)

Tags: utc, dst, timezone-offset, gmt

Wow!  Tons of posts on converting GMT to local time, including correction for DST.  But it seems my need is different.

As the title says, I have a stand-alone embedded system with no O/S.  I'm using NTP to get UTC.  That is used to tag events with an accurate date/time.  I can correct UTC for the current time zone but cannot automatically adjust for DST.

Since there is no O/S, I don't have any of the Windows/Linux data such as time zone.  So there is no way to locally adjust for the GMT offset.

It seems the only way for me to do this is to use an http call to find the offset, and the only way I can think of doing this is using the lon/lat or address.  It would be possible for me to add lon/lat or address to the configuration so this seems like the only option.

I've seen references to sites which return the GMT offset based on location.  Do these sites also automatically adjust for DST?  To do that, they would have to use one of the solutions posted in many places in this forum, but that should be easy enough.

Thanks for the advice and help!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only convert a specific single timestamp to local time, then yes - you can use services such as those [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824).  At least the ones offered by Microsoft and Google do convert a timestamp to the local time in the time zone given, in addition to providing the IANA time zone id.

Additionally, you'll find that the `gettimezonebycoordinates` function in the [Microsoft Azure LBS Time Zone API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/location-based-services/timezone/gettimezonebycoordinates) returns a `PosixTz` value, such as `"PST+8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"`.  This is ideal for embedded systems, as you can set your `TZ` environment variable to this value and then many local APIs (such as with C, and others) will use this value in their conversions.  This approach works best when you may be converting many different local time values and don't want to make an http call for each one.

Be aware, however, that using a POSIX time zone string has some limitations, such as being restricted to a single set of DST transition rules.  They generally work ok for near-current time ranges, but not for historical purposes.

Comment: Hi Matt,Thanks for the suggestions.  I looked into the time zone services you listed and it looks like they should work.  I just need to work on sending/receiving the http code on the embedded side to be sure.